# What jenkins pipeline build variable holds the "commit notification" string?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the detail for a pipeline job, there are lines like "`commit notification <sha1>`",  "`started by timer`", or "`started by user <user>`".  I'd like to get access to that text in the pipeline job, especially if it was the first one.  I've looked through the list of variables provided in the context of the pipeline script (like at "/pipeline-syntax/globals"), but I don't see anything that would obviously contain this.  How can I get this information?

Comment: This info is stored in [build actions](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Action.html). Git info is in action provided by git plugin, 'started by' is in [cause action](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/CauseAction.html). You can get list of action objects like this `currentBuild.rawBuild.getActions()` or a particular one by `currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(hudson.model.CauseAction)`. Such manipulations require sandbox approvals. Also note that `currentBuild.rawBuild` is not Serializable whereas Actons are.

Comment: This looks like it can work. Is there any documentation on how "commit notifications" are rendered in this structure?  I assume it would be some variation of SCMTrigger, but I don't see anything obvious from that class hierarchy.  I suppose I'll just have to print all the fields when something of that type comes through, but that's sort of a backwards way to do this.

Comment: oops: `java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.CauseAction`.

Comment: my code:
`def causes = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(hudson.model.CauseAction);
      def i=0;
      for (cause in causes)
      {
        echo "cause ${i++} : ${cause.getShortDescription()}";
      }`